# Removing (hiding) Magento system URLs

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite, product-urls

I am pretty sure there has to be a simple way to solve, but I just cannot find it.

So, **by default**, there are **2 types** of **product** rules at my store:

```
mystore.com/catalog/product/view/id/177
mystore.com/very-nice-product
```

The problem is that **visitors (and robots)** can access **both versions** and see it as duplicate content.

The solution would be to **redirect** (better yet remove completely) the first URL: `mystore.com/catalog/product/view/id/177`

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that You have to disallow /catalog/product/view/ from google crawl

*Just add below code at robots.txt:*

> Disallow: /catalog/product/view/

Redirection over original product URL is a bad Idea.

***So, the best solution allows system product URL at crawl.***